# Laravel 5.2 error message not shown

Tags: php, laravel

I have come across some answers but the problem for mine are still not fixed.

I just make a fresh app and found out the error message on registration page does not show at all.
I followed some answers I found on this website as below:

1. Just remove , 'middleware' => 'web' from Route::group(array('prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => 'web'), function() in routes.php page

OR

2. Move

\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,

from protected $middlewareGroups to protected $middleware in karnel.php page

(thanks to Atiqur)

Fatal error pops when I click on the register button: Fatal error: Call to a member function first() on string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)

Here are some of my codes for reference. Please help.

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function () {

    Route::get('/', 'UserController@index');

    Route::post('/', 'UserController@update');

    Route::post('/edit', 'UserController@edit');
});


Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/test', 'TestController@index');
```

kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

}

AuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|unique:users|min:3|max:20|alpha_dash',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

registered.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">

                                @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                        <ul>
                                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                                <li>{{ $error->first('name') }}</li>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                        <ul>
                                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                                <li>{{ $error->first('email') }}</li>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                        <ul>
                                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                                <li>{{ $error->first('password') }}</li>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">

                                @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                        <ul>
                                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                                <li>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</li>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i>Register
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

php artisan -v

```
Laravel Framework version 5.2.35
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of `register.blade.php`?

Comment: What exactly version do you use? `php artisan -v`

Comment: Do not go around moving those middleware classes until you've got a better understanding of your application. You can cause some pretty significant errors with `TokenValidationExceptions` randomly popping up throughout your Application. Spent 2 months identifying that we had that problem in one of our Software stacks.

Comment: @Jonathon update my register.blade.php as well

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin it is 5.2.35, updated on the post as well

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks for your input. But I do not think I have edited anything for middleware classes. But I will keep noted for that.

Answer (score 1):

Insert this code in `register.blade.php`

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your input too. I have update my register.blade codes in my post please check. I think mine works similar to yours but still error message just doesn't show. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in In Blade

```
 <div class=" form-group has-feedback{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}"
                   placeholder="Full Name">

            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>`<div class="form-group has-feedback{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}"
                   placeholder="Email">

            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>`<div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">

                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your input. I update my register.blade in my post and i think the code does the similar thing to yours? but it just still doesn't show. Please input more thanks.